# How can I make Grails 2.2 "run-app" detect changes to UrlMappings.groovy?

Tags: grails, url-mapping

When I invoke `run-app` in the Grails console, code changes are auto-detected, and a recompile is triggered.

But when I change `conf/UrlMappings.groovy`, even though I see "Compiling 1 source files" appear in the console, **the live web server doesn't, in fact, update its behavior**.

The problem appears specific to `UrlMappings.groovy`; for example, I can make changes to a controller class and they appear automatically when I hit "refresh" in the browser.

Any thoughts on what's causing this behavior and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `UrlMapping.groovy` is saved after changes are done? I do not see this behavior in Grails 2.2.3, it works as expected.

Comment: Same behavior with v 2.2.0.

Comment: 2.2.4 for what it's worth -- and yes, the file is certainly saved.  As I said, the console even displays output indicating that it's been compiled!